# React Native: Refresh Control not available if I clear the Listview data source

Tags: react-native, pull-to-refresh, react-native-listview

When I set the data source to my listview, refresh control (pull down to refresh) works perfectly fine. In case the data source is empty, I am not able to pull down to refresh the listview.

My listview looks like this:

```
                <View contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
                    <ListView
                        style={styles.container}
                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow={(data) => <NotificationRow {...data}/>}
                        enableEmptySections={true}
                        refreshControl={
                            <RefreshControl
                                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                                onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                                tintColor="#ff0000"
                                title="Loading..."
                                titleColor="#ffffff"
                                colors={['#ffffff']}
                                progressBackgroundColor="#1976D2"
                            />
                        }
                    />
                </View>
```

Is there any props I need to set to Listview or any other way to enable pull down to refresh the listview even if the data source is empty/null?

I am looking for this feature because for the 1st time, I am loading the data from Async Storage. On pull down to refresh, I clear the storage and fetch new data.

Comment: How are you clearing the dataSource? Just setting it to `null`?

Comment: I am clearing it this way:

this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([]),
});

Comment: Try moving out your datasource out of the class. Like  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1!=r2});  This may help.

Comment: Move datasource out of class as suggested. No luck.
I think its related to null data being passed to datasource which doesn't make the Listview render. Since refreshControl is active only if I pull down from a some content rendered by List View. Not able to figure out how to fix this. Seems like a basic use case where if the List View does not show any data, the user may to pull down to refresh.

Comment: @EnieJakiro, thanks for the input. Answered this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Pull down to refresh works if I pull from the region starting from red line]

Figured this out when I tested the app on my phone instead of emulator. The List View is always present even though the datasource is empty. In my case, the listview began where the Text view finished at the red line.

Comment: I absolutely position "no content" placeholder over ListView and set `pointerEvents="none"` on that placeholder. This way, ListView receives touch events!

Comment: @Sood thanks for the answer, would you be able to provide some more detail regarding how you fixed this? I'm having a little trouble following your solution.

Comment: The fix was to set the components layout correctly. I set the text visibility based on a state variable as

`{   !this.state.visible &&
                    this.state.noData &&
                    <View style={styles.noData}>
                        <Text style={styles.noDataText}>
                            No new updates!
                        </Text>
                    </View>
 }`

Then having refreshControl in a ListView wrapped in a ScrollView with contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} set to the ScrollVIew. This way my refreshControl worked right from the top.

Answer (score 2):

You need use prop call `refreshing={true}` and with finish the process, independence if has new data or no you need to set `refreshing={false}` to notify list that you don't have more data and hide loading indicator.

```
render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
          />
        }
        ...
      >
      ...
      </ListView>
    );
```